# Perl: schema language to document and validate API input / output?

Tags: perl, validation, rpc

We're creating a perl and HTTP backed RPC-style API. We're looking for a library with which to document the API input/output and validate especially API input. We originally supported just XML but now are moving towards mostly JSON input/output. But currently: XML and JSON.

Rather than just documenting input and output structures in text for humans, for XML we used [RELAX NG](http://relaxng.org/) embedded in POD to document what input and output looked like and to validate input and optionally output. But that doesn't work for JSON, so currently we can't / don't validate JSON.

We've considered [JSON::Schema](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON%3A%3ASchema), since it can validate the perl data structures, and hence could work for both XML and JSON. But the dependencies are more than we can live with on debian stable. So JSON::Schema is not possible for us.

What other options are there?

Edited to add: Ideally, we'd like validation for input/output data as elaborate as in [Liquid Web's documentation](https://www.liquidweb.com/StormServers/api/docs/v1/Network/DNS/Record/Region.html#method_create). A bonus would be automatic documentation generation (as for Liquid Web) and test case generation too.

Comment: This *might* get a response on softwarerecs, and I think is more on topic there. Looking at the dependencies on http://deps.cpantesters.org/?module=JSON%3A%3ASchema;perl=latest I don't see anything that would worry me if I was writing a web service. Could you be more specific about the problem with them?

Comment: JSON::Schema needs newer versions of Test::More, JSON, ExtUtils::MakeMaker, and other modules missing entirely. I've spent at least a day on this a while back, and after many attempts, each taking more than an hour of CPAN installing dependencies, fixing undeclared dependencies in packages foo, bar, and baz I finally gave up. Today, I just let the Makefile.PL do its CPAN thing - four errors, here 2: `[ERROR] No such module 'Config' found on CPAN` and `Can't locate object method "init_tools" via package "PACK001" at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 661.` Many hours here..

Comment: I'd consider Data::Sah, which I use to document web API's as well as function and CLI's, but it currently has a lot of dependencies too.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using hashes to define and enforce the acceptable input/ouput in your code, and then generate the documentation from the source code itself.  This way you don't have to maintain separate documentation of your api interface, and you'll be more likely to notice issues in your api.  I've done this before with much success :)

Comment: OK ... the code this was done in was pretty darn sophisticated, and so was the API.

Comment: Cool! Sorry, I didn't intend to be derogatory. But parsing perl code is brittle and I was hoping for a way to do this without having to invent the wheel myself.

Comment: No worries. It was a lot of work - and part of why it worked was that we had a very consistently structured api and set of rules for how the allowed inputs/outputs were defined.  A benefit was that we sometimes found bugs in the way that the input/output requirements were set up because the generated documentation made it obvious something was wrong, and either a consistency check error failed or someone viewing the docs could see it was wrong.  It always feels like a win when docs help with code and vice versa :)  Sorry, I don't know of any modules that make this easier though.